# How to delete rows of pyspark dataframe where any column has value less that 1%le or more than 99%le?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I want find the 1%le and 99%le for each column and delete the respective rows of pyspark dataframe.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use percent_rank() function , for example if you have DataFrame with two columns CREDIT and DEBIT ,you can calculate extra columns and use it to filter.
You can't delete rows from DataFrame only filter to new one.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import percent_rank
df3=df.select('CREDIT','DEBIT', percent_rank().over(Window.orderBy(df.CREDIT)).alias("credit_perc"),percent_rank().over(Window.orderBy(df.DEBIT)).alias("debit_perc"))\
  .where('debit_perc >=0.99 or debit_perc <=0.01 ').where('credit_perc >=0.99 or credit_perc <=0.91')
```